# How To Fetch all customer name in multi select in custom admin form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminform, multiselect-attribute, customer-collection

I Want To fetch all customer name in multi select  in my form using customer collection

**Following is my form file**

```
<?php

 namespace Magneto\AppNotification\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab;

 use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic; 
 use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
 use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
 use Magento\Framework\Registry;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
 use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config;


 class Info extends Generic implements TabInterface
  {
  /**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Registry $registry
 * @param FormFactory $formFactory
 * @param Config $wysiwygConfig
 * @param Status $newsStatus
 * @param array $data
 */


 public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Registry $registry,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    array $data = []
) {

    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);

}

/**
 * Prepare form fields
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form
 */
protected function _prepareForm()
{


    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('appnotification_appnotification');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('notification_');
    $form->setFieldNameSuffix('notification');


    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('AppNotification')]
    );

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField(
            'id',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'id']
        );
    }
    $fieldset->addField(
        'title',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'title',
            'label'    => __('Title'),
            'required'     => true
        ]
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'subtitle',
        'text',
        [
            'name'        => 'subtitle',
            'label'    => __('Sub Title'),
            'required'     => true
        ]
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'image',
        'image',
        [
            'label' => __('Upload Image'),
            'name' => 'image',
            'required'=>true
        ]
    );
    $data = $model->getData();
    $form->setValues($data);
    $this->setForm($form);


    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

/**
 * Prepare label for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('AppNotification Info');
}

/**
 * Prepare title for tab
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('AppNotification Info');
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}


}
```

[image: Here I Want To add customer filed where i want to fetch all customer name]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your module block

```
public function getCustomerdata()
{
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customersdata = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
->getCollection()->getData();
return $customersdata;
}
```

Then add this in your module phtml file

```
<?php /*****call the block funtion in phtml*****/ ?>
$customersdata = $block->getCustomerdata();

<?php /*****It is multi select field for customer name*****/ ?>
<div class="admin__field">
    <label for="customer_name" class="admin__field-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Name') ?></label>
    <div class="admin__field-control">
        <select name="customernames[]" id="customernames" class="admin__control-multiselect" multiple>
            <?php
                foreach ($customersdata as $customerdata ):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $customerdata ['firstname'] ?>" ><?php echo $customerdata ['firstname'] ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I hope this will help** and I don't test this code if there is any syntax issue then tell me

Comment: I Want To Fetch it in block i am displaying form using block